# Use Cloudfront with Microfrontends hosted in s3 fails to fetch moduleEntry.js

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, webpack, amazon-cloudfront

My set up is a web app that serves as a hub and 3 other web apps that are referenced by the hub. The microfrontends are built using React.js and webpack and they are deployed in AWS S3 as static website. When i open the site from the cloudfront url, i get a 404 error that it could not retrieve the moduleEntry.js for each of the microfrontends referenced. All the buckets contain an index.html, main.js and the moduleEntry.js files (except from the hub that does not have the latest).

My distribution goes like this: (I changed some values for privacy)

```
{
    "ETag": "-----------------",
    "Distribution": {
        "Id": "-----------------",
        "ARN": "arn:aws:cloudfront::344875100545:distribution/-----------------",
        "Status": "Deployed",
        "LastModifiedTime": "2023-06-23T19:53:58.321000+00:00",
        "InProgressInvalidationBatches": 0,
        "DomainName": "------------------.cloudfront.net",
        "ActiveTrustedSigners": {
            "Enabled": false,
            "Quantity": 0
        },
        "ActiveTrustedKeyGroups": {
            "Enabled": false,
            "Quantity": 0
        },
        "DistributionConfig": {
            "CallerReference": "------------------------------------",
            "Aliases": {
                "Quantity": 1,
                "Items": [
                    "--------.net"
                ]
            },
            "DefaultRootObject": "",
            "Origins": {
                "Quantity": 1,
                "Items": [
                    {
                        "Id": "my-deployed-s3-website.amazonaws.com",
                        "DomainName": "my-deployed-s3-website.amazonaws.com",
                        "OriginPath": "",
                        "CustomHeaders": {
                            "Quantity": 0
                        },
                        "CustomOriginConfig": {
                            "HTTPPort": 80,
                            "HTTPSPort": 443,
                            "OriginProtocolPolicy": "http-only",
                            "OriginSslProtocols": {
                                "Quantity": 1,
                                "Items": [
                                    "TLSv1.2"
                                ]
                            },
                            "OriginReadTimeout": 30,
                            "OriginKeepaliveTimeout": 5
                        },
                        "ConnectionAttempts": 3,
                        "ConnectionTimeout": 10,
                        "OriginShield": {
                            "Enabled": false
                        },
                        "OriginAccessControlId": ""
                    }
                ]
            },
            "OriginGroups": {
                "Quantity": 0
            },
            "DefaultCacheBehavior": {
                "TargetOriginId": "my-deployed-s3-website",
                "TrustedSigners": {
                    "Enabled": false,
                    "Quantity": 0
                },
                "TrustedKeyGroups": {
                    "Enabled": false,
                    "Quantity": 0
                },
                "ViewerProtocolPolicy": "redirect-to-https",
                "AllowedMethods": {
                    "Quantity": 2,
                    "Items": [
                        "HEAD",
                        "GET"
                    ],
                    "CachedMethods": {
                        "Quantity": 2,
                        "Items": [
                            "HEAD",
                            "GET"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "SmoothStreaming": false,
                "Compress": true,
                "LambdaFunctionAssociations": {
                    "Quantity": 0
                },
                "FunctionAssociations": {
                    "Quantity": 0
                },
                "FieldLevelEncryptionId": "",
                "CachePolicyId": "-------------------------"
            },
            "CacheBehaviors": {
                "Quantity": 0
            },
            "CustomErrorResponses": {
                "Quantity": 0
            },
            "Comment": "",
            "Logging": {
                "Enabled": false,
                "IncludeCookies": false,
                "Bucket": "",
                "Prefix": ""
            },
            "PriceClass": "PriceClass_All",
            "Enabled": true,
            "Restrictions": {
                "GeoRestriction": {
                    "RestrictionType": "none",
                    "Quantity": 0
                }
            },
            "WebACLId": "",
            "HttpVersion": "http2",
            "IsIPV6Enabled": true,
            "ContinuousDeploymentPolicyId": "",
            "Staging": false
        }
    }
}
```

I saw same examples that might fix this like creating an invalidation in the cloudfront distrubution for the path "/*" or creating custom error responses but none of these worked.

Comment: Shouldn't your defaultRootObject should be index.html?